# How do I prefix a constant to all the rows in a flat file from within an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package with an *`Execute Process Task`* on Control Flow tab. I am calling *`notepad.exe`* within the task to read a text file. I am trying to replace **`\r\n`** with **`\r\n\test`** so that the text test is prefixed on the first column of all the rows. Thie does not yield the correct results.

#### Text file data:

```
Line 1{CR}{LF}
Line 2{CR}{LF}
Line 3
```

#### Expected output:

```
TestLine 1{CR}{LF}
TestLine 2{CR}{LF}
TestLine 3
```

I am unable to achieve this output using *notepad.exe* using *Execute Process Task*. How can I achieve this output using *Execute Process Task*? Are there any other tasks in SSIS that can do this?

Comment: yuup \r\n with \r\n\test I just corrected the title. I just wanted to appen test in begining of my column value so it would be test 1

Comment: I dont know any other process that could do it so I am running execute process task, if there is any other tool that could do it, please let me know. yes I am reading a text file, it is flat file with one single column having value. Yes I need to add test in front of all column 1 values with space after test so for example it would be test 1 and next row would be test 2. and yes save file as a text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Execute Process Task:

*Execute Process Task* is not the appropriate task for what you are trying to do. You could `Script Task` to read the file contents and prefix the lines with a text of your choice or you could use the *`Data Flow Task`* to achieve the same through configuration without any coding.

#### SSIS 2012 package illustrating an example:

Below package created using SSIS 2012 illustrates how to read the contents of a text file and then prefix each line with a text phrase to write the output to a different flat file.

Let's assume that you need to read a file named *`Products.txt`* that has the following information with each line ending with carriage return and line feed characters *`{CR}{LF}`*

[image: Source File]

Create an SSIS package named *`SO_15213317.dtsx`*. This sample uses SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) 2012 to create the package but the logic in this example is applicable to older SSIS versions 2005 through 2008 R2.

Drag and drop a *`Data Flow Task`* onto the *Control Flow* tab. Right-click on the *Connection Manager* tab at the bottom of the package and click *`New Flat File Connection...`*. This connection manager will be used to read the source file.

[image: SSIS Package]

On the Flat File Connection Manager Editor, perform the following steps:

- Set the Name to *`FILE_Products`*
- Set the description to *`Read the products information from flat file.`*
- Browse to the location where the file is located and select the file.
- Rest of the properties will be inherited based on the data in the file.
- Check the box *`Column names in the first data row`* if there are column headers in the file
- Click *`Columns`* page.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - General]

Leave the *Columns* tab with default settings and click *`Advanced`* page.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - Columns]

Advanced page will automatically configure the column name based on the header information and SSIS will make a good guess about the data type too. In this case, it has decided that the column data type is string.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - Advanced]

Click the *Preview* tab to simply look the file data. Click OK to close the Flat File Connection Manager Editor.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor - Preview]

Double-click the *Data Flow Task* on the Control Flow tab to switch to the *Data Flow* tab. On the Data Flow Task, drag and drop a *`Flat File Source`* to read the source file. Configure the *Flat File Source* as shown below.

[image: Flat File Source Editor - Connection Manager]

The columns will automatically configure. Click OK to close the Flat File Source Editor.

[image: Flat File Source Editor - Columns]

To prefix the text **`Test`** on all the rows, you need to make use of a *`Derived Column Transformation`*. Drag and drop a *Derived Column Transformation* after the Flat File Source. Connect the *Flat File Source* to the *Derived Column Transformation*. You can add a new column or replace an existing column. The example adds a new column with the following expression. This expression prefixes the text Test to the incoming values of column *`ProductName`* and then type casts them to SSIS data type DT_WSTR of length 54 characters.

```
(DT_WSTR,54)("Test" + ProductName)
```

[image: Derived Column Transformation]

Drag and drop a *`Flat File Destination`* to write the output to another text file. On the *Flat File Destination Editor*, click **`New...`** button to create a new Flat File Connection Manager for destination file.

[image: Flat File Destination Editor - Connection Manager]

Select **`Delimited`** on *`Flat File Format`* dialog and click OK.

[image: Flat File Format]

On the Flat File Connection Manager Editor, perform the following steps:

- Set the Name to *`FILE_NewProducts`*
- Set the description to *`Write the data to the new product flat file..`*
- Browse to the location where the file should be saved and give a name to the file.
- Configure rest of the properties as per requirements.
- Check the box *`Column names in the first data row`* if you need column headers to be written to the file
- Click *`Columns`* page.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager - General]

Configure the Columns page with Row and Column Delimiter.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager - Columns]

On the *Advanced* page, click the column **`ProductName`** column and click *`Delete`*. You can name the column however you would like to.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager - Advanced]

Only the column *`NewProductName`* will remain on the destination connection manager. Click OK.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager - Advanced]

On the *Flat File Destination Editor*, make sure to select the correct flat file connection manager.

[image: File File Destination Editor - Connection Manager]

Click the *Mappings* page to configure the column mappings to write the data.

[image: File File Destination Editor - Columns]

After the Data Flow Tasks are configured, the package should look as shown below.

[image: Data Flow Task]

Execute the package to read the source file and generate the new output file with text prefix.

[image: Package Execution]

The newly generated file `NewProducts.txt` will contain the prefix text phrase **`Test`**

[image: Output File]

#### Other options:

There are various different ways to read a file and you can also read a file using a *`Script Task`*. However, the example here illustrates an appropriate way to read text files in SSIS packages. This should give you an idea about how to design SSIS packages dealing with flat files or delimited files in future.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and great instructions.